# Fatal error when retrieving message object from php helper library

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to retrieve a message object which contains all sms messages associated with a given account. The code I have started with is copy pasted directly from the usage documentation.

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
foreach ($client->account->sms_messages as $message) {
    echo $message->body;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This code does work, in that it will actually retrieve all of the sms messages associated with the account specified with the $sid. However, after the last iteration, it will always throw an uncaught exception:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'AfterSid is required for paging.' in /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio.php:298 Stack trace:

0 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio.php(266): Base_Services_Twilio->_processResponse(Array)

1 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio.php(237): Base_Services_Twilio->_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...', 1)

2 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(125): Base_Services_Twilio->retrieveData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array)

3 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(179): Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPage(8, 50, Array, NULL)

4 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPageGenerator(8, 50, Array, NULL)

5 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio/AutoPagingIterator.php(104): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

6 /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio/AutoPagingIterator.php(77): Services_Twilio_Au in /var/www/includes/twilio-php-library/Services/Twilio.php on line 298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the library related to our deprecation of absolute paging, tracked here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/296 . We implemented server-side code today that should mitigate this error from happening for twilio-php.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. After working with my code today, it appears that this issue has been fixed. Thank you.